# A question about Manual errors

Tags: documentation

I found [this misleading entry](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Edges#Delete_Edge_Loop) in the latest Manual (2.68):

[image]

The '7' should be '11', but as there is no way to enter a key twice, it should be <kbd>G</kbd>.
The 'Edges' should be 'Delete' as there is no option to *Delete Edge loop* in *Mesh > Edges*, and the *Erase menu* is really called the *Delete Menu*.

so I set about trying to find a way to have it corrected.
I worked my way through the 'maze' in blender.org only to find dead ends and outdated information!

Can anyone point me in the right direction?.

Comment: I edited your question to try and make clearer why Edges, 7, and Erase are wrong.

Comment: Corrected wiki doc, however I'm not convinced having these menu items as key-shortcuts in the manual is good. It means every time a menu item is moved/added the key shortcut changes too. We could just document the key for the menu and let the user find the number to press.

Comment: @ideasman42, thanks for that. - I agree, it would be easier to get rid of the NumPad key shortcuts, as far as documentation is concerned. Oh, by the way, you missed the other two errors! :)

Comment: While it's not overly conveniet, 11 translates as ALT-1. The numbers 11 to 19 use the ALT key. Ancient dinosaur knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Editing the Wiki

You will have to create an account by clicking *Log in / create account*:

[image]
[image]

Once you have done so and logged in (click *Log in*), [image] there will be an *edit* button:

[image]

(Note that you won't be able to edit anything until you [verify that you exist](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Terrywallwork/Verification/Message))

and one should read the usual [writing guides](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Meta:Guides/Writer_Guide#Official_Manual_Review_Workflow) and such..

Comment: Yes, 'Edges' is in the Ctrl+E menu, but 'Delete Edge Loop' is not in 'Edges', and this is supposed to be about 'Delete Edge Loop'! Also, there is no such thing as an 'Erase' menu, it is called the 'Delete' menu. '7' refers to the seventh item in the menu which is 'Dissolve Edges', not 'Delete Edge Loop' (which is the eleventh item), and you're right, you can't have '11' (two key hits), so this needs to be re-worded not referring to a Numpad number. Thanks for the guide to editing the wiki.

Comment: @SteveW you are quite right.. I completely missed that. :P

Comment: Whew, I'm so glad we have come to an understanding on this. Thank you :) Could you please add to your answer - how to get to the log in page to edit the wiki?

Comment: @SteveW all you have to do is click "Log in / create account" to get the login screen. updated answer.

Comment: What I'm trying to find out is this: Where do I find this page that your screen shot shows?

Comment: The point that I'm making is that your answer is incomplete. It's not obvious where this page is. :)

Comment: @SteveW Any page on the wiki should have it in the upper right corner.

Comment: Thank you. Honestly, it wasn't that obvious to me :) (it looks different on my computer), although I figured it out and have applied to be able to log in. Now your answer is complete and has a green tick!

Comment: Np. thanks, and I'm glad you got it figured out. :) (and I see you fixed the wiki too ;) )